# Azure Defender for Cloud Add Reader to custom role with only read settings

Tags: azure

`Trying to give only reader access to custom role for Defender cloud permissions where users cant change any permissions in Defender for cloud permissions

Tried adding this permissions notactions of the custom role:
  `"Microsoft.Security/locations/securityPolicies/write",    "Microsoft.Security/locations/securitySolutions/write",               "Microsoft.Security/locations/alerts/write",                    "Microsoft.Security/locations/securityRecommendations/write"`
    
Getting error on not actions:
Validation error: Invalid notAction is present in "notActions" : Microsoft.Security/locations/securityPolicies/write

In actions part  code is like this
"actions": [
"*"]

Trying to give only reader access to custom role for Defender cloud permissions where users cant change any permissions in Defender for cloud permissions`

Comment: Are you using any code template like ARM or Bicep? @Ganapathy

Comment: Json ARM Template

Comment: Have you tried to enable or disable actions via portal by visiting subscription >> Access control blade. @Ganapathy

Answer (score 0):

You can provide actions and no actions as below
`{ "actions": [ "*" ], "notActions": [ "*/Write", "*/Delete" ], "dataActions": [], "notDataActions": [] }`

Comment: Looking for Defender for cloud with only read permissions

Comment: Microsoft.Security/locations/securityPolicies/*/write i tried save it, on Review + Update getting this error
'Microsoft.Security/locations/securityPolicies/*/write' does not match any of the actions supported by the providers.
Please help